# Rails radio button stuck on "1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, radio-button

Rails 3.2; adding radio buttons to a form; generated HTML is this:

```
 <label>
          (*) Image for slide-show
          <br>
          <input checked="checked" id="featured_company_image_source_1" name="featured_company[image_source]" type="radio" value="1" />
          Use the Company logo
          <br>
          <input id="featured_company_image_source_2" name="featured_company[image_source]" type="radio" value="2" />
          Select a different image
          <div class='clear'></div>
        </label>
```

yet the radio button is stuck on the first item; clicking the second item turns it on while the mouse button is depressed, then it bounces back to the first item.  Looks just the same as other radio buttons we've created... What the heck is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange but true: this is some kind of bug in FireFox: the site displays correctly on Chrome for Linux & Windows, but FireFox for Linux and Windows both have this problem. Firefox also has problems handling some of the CSS on the site, again on both Linux and Windows while Chrome displays correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Probably some javascript switches it back on. the HTML looks correct

Comment: Thanks @Nikolay... I was beginning to think I was missing something totaly obvious.